# SQL - 2 SQL parts into 1

Tags: sql

Hello i have these 2 metrics that works good so far:

```
-- --------------------------------------------
-- Nb Unique Accounts 
-- -------------------------------------------

    select count(distinct(O.user_id))
    from DB.order O LEFT JOIN DB.orderCompleted OrC
        ON O.id  = OrC.order_id
    where reason in ('2') 



-- --------------------------------------------
-- Nb Accounts that are eighter deactivated or invalid
-- -------------------------------------------

    select count(distinct(O.user_id))
    from DB.order O JOIN DB.orderCompleted OrC
        ON O.id  = OrC.order_id
    where reason (0,1)
```

QUESTION#1: We now need a 3 rd metric that will caclculate the % of nb of accounts that are eighter deactivated or invalid. How could we acheive that ?

QUESTION#2: We would also like to only have 1 big SQL performing all 3 small queries above in order to then use this unioned or joined big sql into a Business Intelligence Reporting Tool that allows to use sql coding in order to display it in a crossTab

Comment: Use each of these queries as a derived table and cross join.  Then you add the formula for the percentage in the outer select.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: That first query seems wrong to me. I think you want an INNER JOIN there. The select list only uses a column from the `order` table. The `reason` column in the WHERE clause _could_ be from orderCompleted, but if it is, it's used in a way where an INNER JOIN would still work. Alternatively, an INNER JOIN might cause rows you need to be excluded. However, this can only happen if the `reason` column is part of the `Order` table, and in that case you don't need to use the `orderCompleted` at all and can remove the JOIN entirely.

Comment: Also, for the second query, are you missing an `IN` between "reason" and "(0,1)"? And what is the data type of reason? You use it like string in the first query, but like a number in the 2nd. What is the schema of those two tables?

Comment: Which of the two tables does the column `reason` reside in?

Comment: @HLGEM : Do you mean something more like
SELECT (col1/col2) AS Percent...
From ( Select col1, col2 from ...)
Where ...

Comment: @Joel: The reason i was doing a LEFT JOIN was because it is possible that data from the Order O table might not have corrresponding data in the OrderCompleted OrC table.   Also, the good syntax would of been  in (2)

Comment: @Thorsten : where O.reason in (2) is the correct syntax as for the [reason] column is part of the "order" table.

Comment: @sanchoniathon It comes down to the `reason` column. It's not clear from the question which table has that column. If `reason` is part of the `Order` table, then you don't need `orderCompleted` table at all and can remove the JOIN entirely. If it's part of `orderCompleted`, then a missing record in `orderCompleted` would still fail the query, and you can just do an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @sanchoniathon Seeing that last comment now, you can reduce the first query down to just `select count(distinct user_id)
    from DB.order where reason = 2` and you'll get the same results. Try it. For the 2nd query, the equivalent would be this:  `select count(distinct user_id)
    from DB.order where reason in (0,1)` However, because you used an INNER JOIN, the 2nd query currently filters out records with no completed orders, and so you might exclude some user_id values that way.

Comment: @Joel: The purpose of (well the goal is) joining tables "Order" and "OrderCompleted" is to be able to get some fact columns from the "OrderCompleted" table but that also takes into consideration the fact that the [reason] column from the Order table has some specific values BUt also because we will need to add some other conditions in the where clause using the column [WayOfPayment] from the [OrderCompleted] table and before doing so we need to join these tables using the O.id  = OrC.order_id

Comment: @Joel: Something like this would be on of our end goal for each metric                                                                                              
    select count(distinct(O.user_id))
    from DB.order O LEFT JOIN DB.orderCompleted OrC
        ON O.id  = OrC.order_id
    where O.reason = (2) and OrC.WayOfPayment = 'ThisWay'

Comment: This makes no sense. Do you even know what a `LEFT JOIN` is? Why do you outer join and then break it with a WHERE clause criteria?

Comment: Thanks to all.

@Thorsten Kettner: In fact i know a left outer join will display all rows from left side 
of our join wether it finds a corresponding match in the table from the right side of 
the left outer join.

I'm not sure how to acheive this: 
What i want is to COUNT THE NUMBER OF USER_ID that has the [Reason] column from the "Order" table = 2 
as well as when the [WayOfPayment] columns from "OrderCompleted" table value equals to 'ThisWay'.
So thanks for all the feed-back so far.

Comment: This is not in your request. I don't see any WayOfPayment mentioned there. Instead you were asking how to get a percentage from the results and how to get the two queries into one. At least this is how I and the others have understood your request. It seems you have a *new* question now, so make this a *new* request. When doing so, explain your data, i.e. tell us what reasons 1, 2, 3 mean, show sample data and according desired result.

Comment: As to what a `LEFT JOIN` does: `from DB.order O LEFT JOIN DB.orderCompleted OrC` tries to find matches in orderCompleted for each order record. When there is no match, you get the rows still, but with all orderCompleted columns set to null. `where ... and OrC.WayOfPayment = 'ThisWay'` however dismisses all rows where WayOfPayment is null. So you make this look like an outer join, but after all it's just an inner join you are running here.

Comment: Thank you all. I will therefore open a new issue. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    count(distinct CASE WHEN reason = 2 THEN O.user_id ELSE NULL END) AS "Nb Unique Accounts",
    count(distinct CASE WHEN OrC.Oder_id IS NOT NULL AND reason in (1,2) THEN O.user_id ELSE NULL END) AS "Nb Accounts deactivated/invalid",
    count(distinct CASE WHEN OrC.Oder_id IS NOT NULL AND reason in (1,2) THEN O.user_id ELSE NULL END) / count(distinct O.user_id) As "Percent deactived/invalid"
FROM DB.order O 
LEFT JOIN DB.orderCompleted OrC  ON O.id  = OrC.order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
select count(distinct(O.user_id))
from DB.order O LEFT JOIN DB.orderCompleted OrC
    ON O.id  = OrC.order_id
where O.reason in ('2')
```

you are counting user IDs from table `order` no matter whether they have related `orderCompleted` records or not. You can simplify this to:

```
select count(distinct user_id)
from DB.order
where reason = 2;
```

In the query

```
select count(distinct(O.user_id))
from DB.order O JOIN DB.orderCompleted OrC
    ON O.id  = OrC.order_id
where reason (0,1)
```

you want matches in `orderCompleted`. You can simplyfy this to:

```
select count(distinct user_id)
from DB.order
where reason in (0, 1)
and id in (select order_id from ordercompleted);
```

To get both counts, use conditional aggregation. You can also do math:

```
select 
  count(distinct case when reason = 2 then user_id end),
  count(distinct case when reason in (0, 1) and id in (select order_id from ordercompleted) then user_id end),
  count(distinct case when reason in (0, 1) and id in (select order_id from ordercompleted) then user_id end) /
  count(distinct user_id)
from DB.order
where reason in (0, 1, 2);
```

Or move the subquery to your `FROM` clause:

```
select 
  count(distinct case when o.reason = 2 then o.user_id end),
  count(distinct case when o.reason in (0, 1) and oc.id is not null then o.user_id end),
  count(distinct case when o.reason in (0, 1) and oc.id is not null then o.user_id end) /
  count(distinct user_id)
from DB.order o
left join (select distinct order_id from ordercompleted) oc using (order_id)
where o.reason in (0, 1, 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi to all people in this great forum.

See  near the end of rhis post message for the correct MySql pieces of code i whish to have in only 1 big query.

Also, the reason i was doing a LEFT JOIN was because it is possible that data from the Order O table might not have corrresponding data in the OrderCompleted OrC table.

@HLGEM : You mean something like

```
SELECT (col1/col2) AS Percent...
From ( Select col1, col2 from ...)
Where ...
```

---

-- Nb Unique Accounts

---

```
select count(distinct(O.user_id)) 
from DB.order O LEFT JOIN DB.orderCompleted OrC ON O.id = OrC.order_id where O.reason in (2)
```

---

-- Nb Accounts that are eighter deactivated or invalid

---

```
select count(distinct(O.user_id))
from DB.order O JOIN DB.orderCompleted OrC ON O.id = OrC.order_id 
where O.reason in (0,1)
```